# Programme crashes when add dictionary to array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsarray

I have a crash problem when I am trying to add object into array, I think I have problem with the way i create object and release it. But I am not quite sure cause I am still kinda weak with memory management

```
 NSMutableDictionary *schools = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [schools setObject:name forKey:kFavoriteSchoolName];
    //load data is getting data from NSUserDefault which I save
    NSMutableArray *loadedArray = [self loadData];

//if loadedarray has object in there, then continue adding schools to it or make new array
if([loadedArray count] > 0)
{
    [loadedArray addObject:schools];

    > // it crashes here


    [schools release];

    return loadedArray;
} else
{ 

    //It will add the school to the array for the first time if there is nothing when it loaded.

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    [tempArray addObject:schools];

    [schools release];

    return tempArray;
}
```

This function help add the school into favorite list. I cant add once, but it crashes when I add it again.

This is my code of loadData function

```
- (NSMutableArray *) loadData
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    NSMutableArray *list = [userDefault objectForKey:kSchoolList];
    
    return list;
    
}
```

The log does not say anything but this: Thread 1: Program received signal "SGABRT"

when I first run the programme and add, it is fine, I add school again then only it crashes, crashes at [loadedArray addobject:schools];

Comment: Could you post the crash log?

Comment: NSMutableArray *loadedArray = [self loadData];
make sure the array returned by `[self loadData]` is mutable too...other wise do this and try again `NSMutableArray *loadedArray = [[self loadData]mutable copy]; `

Comment: Try this NSMutableArray *loadedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self loadData]];

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, mutableCopy is correct. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks clear. The only white spot is the way you create array in `[self loadData]` method.

You mentioned that you restore it from `NSUserDefaults`. Probably you just return it by `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"schools"]`.

Since `objectForKey:` method returns `id` type object you don't get a warning telling that `objectForKey:` returns `NSArray` not `NSMutableArray`.

Just make something like this:

```
return [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"schools"]];
```

I hope I guessed your code right ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you put up the log, so we'll know what the crash actually is. I assume at some point you are storing values of tempArray into loaded. Try changing your code to this

```
 NSMutableDictionary *schools = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [schools setObject:name forKey:kFavoriteSchoolName];
    //load data is getting data from NSUserDefault which I save
    NSMutableArray *loadedArray = [[self loadData] retain];

//if loadedarray has object in there, then continue adding schools to it or make new array
if([loadedArray count] > 0)
{
    if([loadedArray isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    [loadedArray addObject:schools];
    }
    else {NSLog(@"Not a mutable array");}

    > // it crashes here


    [schools release];

    return [loadedArray autorelease];
} else
{ 
    [loadedArray release];
    //It will add the school to the array for the first time if there is nothing when it loaded.

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    [tempArray addObject:schools];

    [schools release];

    return tempArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, I just edited my question. Please take a look again and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> I found out that you didn't initialize your array loadArray. You
>   cannot add any value to uninitialized NSMutableArray.

You need to start with initialization.

```
NSMutableArray *loadArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then populate data to your array

```
[loadArray  addObjectsFromArray:[self loadData]];
```